# How to split a string in an array

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x, split

I need to split a string at a '.' and everything after is irrelevant I just need the first element at index[0].

I have tried using the .split('.')[0] in a for loop however, the output never changes.

The text.txt file looks like this [{"description":"large", "istrue":"yes","name":"george.doe.jane", "clear":"true", "money": 5000}] It has more than one object but they are all built the same.

```
output_file = open ('text.txt', 'r')
json_array = json.load(output_file)
json_list = []
for item in json_array:
    name = "name"
    money = "money"
    json_items = {name:None, money:None}
    json_items[name.split('.')[0]] = item[name.split('.')[0]]
    json_items[money] = item[money]
    json_list.append(json_items)
```

The output currently looks like {'name': 'george.doe.jane', 'money':5000}
I would like it to look like {'name': 'george','doe','jane', 'money':5000}

Comment: The text.txt file looks like this 

[{'description':'large', 'istrue':'yes','name':'jane.doe', 'clear':'true', 'money': 5000}] It has more than one object but they are all built the same.

Comment: Do I need to append instead of read?

Comment: It was double quotes.

Comment: I'm sorry, new to python. Is an embedded dictionary the proper syntax?

Comment: I have updated the question. I just need the output split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `with` context manager to open your file, and split the name on `.` to create the list of names

```
import json

#Open the file
with open ('text.txt', 'r') as output_file:

    #Load the json array
    json_array = json.load(output_file)

    #Iterate through the list and append the resultant dictionary to the list
    json_list = [{'name': item['name'].split('.'), 'money': item['money']} for item in json_array]

    print(json_list)
```

The output will be

```
[{'name': ['george', 'doe', 'jane'], 'money': 5000}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just using `.split()` wrong: fair enough. Here's an example of its usage:

```
s = 'h.e.l.l.o'
a = s.split('.')
# ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

So your `for` loop maybe should look a bit more like:

```
for i in json_array:
    json_list.append({'name': i['name'].split('.'), 'money': i['money']})
```

output should be

```
json_list = [{'name': ['george', 'doe', 'jane'], 'money': 5000}]
```